# Avoid div overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a piece of code that when user hover the slider bar, a box will appear. Everything works as expected but when the user move the mouse to the beginning or to the end of the slider, the box overflow the content.

I'm looking for a way that keep the box inside the blue area

Here is my code =>

```js
var left = document.getElementById('core').getBoundingClientRect().left - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  let x = ((e.clientX + window.pageXOffset) - left);
  document.getElementById("thumbnail").style.left = (x + "px");
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.core {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
}

.range {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.range:hover + .thumbnail {
  display: block;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: auto;
  margin: 0;
  width: 12em;
  height: 7em;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.thumbnail::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  transform: translateY(-19%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="core" class="core">
    <input id="progress" class="range" type='range' min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0">
    <div id="thumbnail" class="thumbnail"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[ If you want jsfiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/ram9wc65/ ]

Here is a image that show +- the expected output =>
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4GLx.png) (I cannot embed images yet)

How can I fix this? How can I keep the box inside of blue area? I spent many hours working on it but no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your onMouseMove function, you need to get the width of the thumbnail and divide that by 2, to get the minimum left position and calculate the maximum right position (width - minimum).
Then make sure you set the left property of the thumbnail no smaller than the minimum and no larger than the calculated maximum.

Comment: Could you please explain again the maximum right position? I didnt understand this part very well

Comment: Get the width of `.core`, subtract half the width of `.thumbnail`. That's your maximum left.

Comment: Like this? => https://prnt.sc/ecI88Fyta-1G 
Not working for me =(

Comment: width = .thumbnail

Comment: You have to get the width of an element like this:
`document.querySelectorAll('.core')[0].style.width;` or with jQuery
`$('.core').width();`